# В Asp.Net Core заинжектить сервис с парметрами, где один из параметров - вложенный сервис, а остальные параметры - обычные переменные

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Как пробросить несколько параметров в конструктор, где один из параметров - это вложенный сервис, а второй параметр - обычная переменная. Видел статьи, где объясняется как это сделать с вложенным сервисом. Там рекоммендуют через создание Factory. Но у меня есть еще один параметр. Ниже пример того, как выглядит мой сервис.

```
class RootService : IRootService
{
   private readonly INestedService<RootService> _nestedService;
   private bool _myParam;

   public RootService(INestedService<RootService> nestedService, bool myParam) =>
      (_nestedService, _myParam) = (nestedService, myParam);
 
}
```

Ниже пример того, как выглядит регистрация зависимостей.

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(<INestedService, NestedService>());
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(<IRootService, RootService>( _ => new RootService(myParam)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получаете уже зарегистрированную зависимость из DI-контейнера, а остальные параметры задаёте явно.

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRootService, RootService>(x =>
    new RootService(x.GetRequiredService<INestedService<RootService>>(), true)
);
```